# Manage Microsoft DHCP from Linux

Tags: windows, linux, active-directory, dhcp

Is it possible to manage a DHCP server that runs on a windows 2003 machine from linux? I have searched but can't find anything.

I am hoping to script something up in linux (whatever language), that would allow me to add/remove dhcp leases via command line in linux (ie: ./add-dhcp-lease.pl   )

Anyone know if this is even possible?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/2003_Server/A_3516-Configuring-DHCP-server-from-command-line.html?

Comment: You could remote desktop from *nix into the win box...

Comment: Maybe [winexe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/) + command line dhcp is what you want.  probably easier to just RDP in though.

Answer (score 1):

> allow me to add/remove dhcp leases via command line in linux (ie: ./add-dhcp-lease.pl )

That pre-supposes that the MS dhcp server has some API or CLI interface itself. AFAIK, although it uses a JET DB to maintain the config, this is not intended to be accessible by other programs, and there is no published API. However the [netsh](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732418%28WS.10%29.aspx) command is a CLI tool available on MSWindows boxes for configuring the DHCP server. How you get the instructions from the Linux box to the MSWindows box is a different can of worms. Telnet is very insecure - but you could tunnel it over SSL (e.g. using [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) at both ends).

It would be massively simpler to run a dhcpd on the linux box.

Comment: netsh and win32 APIs are the only ways I know of to remotely control Windows DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I think my using a combination of winexe and netsh from a linux script I may be able to get this to work.

I know that RDP'ing and doing it by hand would be the preferred way, but I wanted some automation to make our lives easier.

I appreciate all of your time!

Thanks!

Oh, and I would love to be running dhcpd on a linux box, believe me, but I'm the only one who wants to, haha. ;/